# want to delete item from mongodb database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**NodeJS**
Whenever I click the delete button it gives me error can not post on webpage and does not delete the item.

```
router.post('/delete/:id',function(req,res){
    rental.deleteOne({_id: req.params.id});
    res.redirect('/rental');
 });
```

ejs:

```
<% data.forEach((y)=>{ %>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="text-start"></th>
              <td><%=y.carname %></td>
              <td><%=y.numberplate %></td>
              <td><%=y.rent %></td>
              <td>
                <form action="delete/<%=y._id %>" method="post">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form></td>
            </tr>
<% }) %>
```

I am getting cannot post on webpage.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Cannot POST /rental/delete/6498adb138bead19ee9f54c9

Comment: `/delete/:id` this is the defined route in the code, but the url having `/rental/`. how did you configured your application? `/rental/<url>` all your request having this prefix?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an updated version of your code to handle the delete operation correctly:**

```
router.get('/delete/:id', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    await rental.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.redirect('/rental');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting rental:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

In this updated code, the route is changed from post to get because the delete operation is typically performed through a GET request (e.g., clicking on a delete button). By using async/await, we ensure that the deleteOne() method, which returns a promise, is awaited before redirecting the user to the /rental route.